# Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss

I would like to ask if somebody could help to resolve this problem because I'm stuck with it and I don't know where the problem could be. Until now I developed my application under Glassfish Server 4. Now I deceided to change my server for WildFly and I edited some configs to be able to run it on Wild Fly.

Project is created using maven, and I run it using     mvn install wildfly:deploy   command from terminal.

Here is **server log**:

```
09:42:29,625 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "sk.fri.war" (runtime-name: "sk.fri.war")  
09:42:31,906 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for FRIApvvPU  
09:42:32,073 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) JBAS011409: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'sk.fri.war#FRIApvvPU'  
09:42:32,074 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [  
  name: FRIApvvPU  
  ...]  
09:42:33,398 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment sk.fri.war  
09:42:33,416 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-7) JNDI bindings for session bean named LoginManagementService in deployment unit deployment "sk.fri.war" are as follows:  


  java:global/sk.fri/LoginManagementService!sk.fri.service.LoginManagementService  
  java:app/sk.fri/LoginManagementService!sk.fri.service.LoginManagementService  
  java:module/LoginManagementService!sk.fri.service.LoginManagementService  
  java:global/sk.fri/LoginManagementService  
  java:app/sk.fri/LoginManagementService  
  java:module/LoginManagementService  


09:42:33,417 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-7) JNDI bindings for session bean named MeasurementProcessingService in deployment unit deployment "sk.fri.war" are as follows:  


  java:global/sk.fri/MeasurementProcessingService!sk.fri.service.MeasurementProcessingService  
  java:app/sk.fri/MeasurementProcessingService!sk.fri.service.MeasurementProcessingService  
  java:module/MeasurementProcessingService!sk.fri.service.MeasurementProcessingService  
  java:global/sk.fri/MeasurementProcessingService  
  java:app/sk.fri/MeasurementProcessingService  
  java:module/MeasurementProcessingService  


09:42:33,417 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-7) JNDI bindings for session bean named CityService in deployment unit deployment "sk.fri.war" are as follows:  


  java:global/sk.fri/CityService!sk.fri.service.CityService  
  java:app/sk.fri/CityService!sk.fri.service.CityService  
  java:module/CityService!sk.fri.service.CityService  
  java:global/sk.fri/CityService  
  java:app/sk.fri/CityService  
  java:module/CityService  


09:42:33,557 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.3)  
09:42:33,558 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: sk.fri.war  
09:42:33,565 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = sk.fri.war_org.postgresql.Driver_9_3  
09:42:33,567 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment sk.fri.war  
09:42:33,584 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) JBAS011409: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'sk.fri.war#FRIApvvPU'  
09:42:49,079 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect  
09:42:49,081 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  
09:42:49,148 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  
09:42:49,231 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."sk.fri.war#FRIApvvPU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."sk.fri.war#FRIApvvPU": org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService]  
  at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]  
  at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]  
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]  
  at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:474)  
  at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]  
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]  
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]  
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]  
  at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)  
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService]  
  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:173) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]  
  at org.hibernate.envers.event.EnversIntegrator.integrate(EnversIntegrator.java:65) [hibernate-envers-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]  
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:311) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]  
  at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]  
  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]  
  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]  
  at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]  
  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]  
  at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44) [jipijapa-hibernate4-3-1.0.1.Final.jar:]  
  at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]  
  ... 8 more  


09:42:49,237 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 5) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "sk.fri.war")]) - failure description: {  
    "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"sk.fri.war#FRIApvvPU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"sk.fri.war#FRIApvvPU\": org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService]  
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService]"},  
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.\"sk.fri\".\"sk.fri\".DefaultDataSource is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDS]"]  
}  
09:42:49,243 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 5) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "sk.fri.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:  
{  
    "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"sk.fri.war#FRIApvvPU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"sk.fri.war#FRIApvvPU\": org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService]  
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService]"},  
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.\"sk.fri\".\"sk.fri\".DefaultDataSource is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDS]"]  
}  
09:42:49,246 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010418: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = sk.fri.war_org.postgresql.Driver_9_3  
09:42:49,248 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment sk.fri.war  
09:42:49,264 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'sk.fri.war#FRIApvvPU'  
09:42:49,322 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment sk.fri.war (runtime-name: sk.fri.war) in 79ms  
09:42:49,324 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 5) JBAS014774: Service status report  
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:  
      service jboss.deployment.unit."sk.fri.war".component.MeasurementProcessingService.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."sk.fri.war".component.MeasurementProcessingService.START]  
      service jboss.deployment.unit."sk.fri.war".component.MeasurementProcessingService.VIEW."sk.fri.service.MeasurementProcessingService".LOCAL (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."sk.fri.war".component.MeasurementProcessingService.START]  
      service jboss.deployment.unit."sk.fri.war".component.MeasurementProcessingService.WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."sk.fri.war".component.MeasurementProcessingService.START]  
      service jboss.deployment.unit."sk.fri.war".component.MeasurementProcessingService.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."sk.fri.war".component.MeasurementProcessingService.START]  
JBAS014776:    Newly corrected services:  
      service jboss.deployment.unit."sk.fri.war".component.LoginManagementService.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (no longer required)  
      service jboss.deployment.unit."sk.fri.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".WeldInstantiator (no longer required)  
      service jboss.deployment.unit."sk.fri.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".WeldInstantiator (no longer required)  
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./apvv (no longer required)  
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."sk.fri.war#FRIApvvPU"
```

My **standalone.xml** config (included only parts I have added or edited):

```
<datasources>  
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/jBossJaasPostgres" pool-name="jBossJaasPostgres" enabled="true" use-ccm="false" jta="false" use-java-context="true">  
        <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/apvv</connection-url>  
  <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>  
        <driver>postgresql</driver>  
        <pool>  
            <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>  
            <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>  
        </pool>  
        <security>  
            <user-name>username</user-name>  
            <password>password</password>  
        </security>  
        <validation>  
            <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>  
            <background-validation>false</background-validation>  
        </validation>  
        <statement>  
            <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>  
        </statement>  
    </datasource>  
    <drivers>  
        <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">  
            <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>  
        </driver>  
    </drivers>  
</datasources>
```

then default datasource:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">  
    <jpa default-datasource="java:jboss/datasources/jBossJaasPostgres"/>  
</subsystem>
```

and under security domains (because I use JAAS)

```
<security-domain name="apvvJaas">  
    <authentication>  
        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">  
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/jBossJaasPostgres"/>  
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from v_user_group where username = ?"/>  
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select rolename, 'Roles' from v_user_group where username = ?"/>  
            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>  
            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="Hex"/>  
            <module-option name="hashUserPassword" value="true"/>  
            <module-option name="hashStorePassword" value="true"/>  
        </login-module>  
    </authentication>  
</security-domain>
```

My **persistence.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>  
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">  
  <persistence-unit name="FRIApvvPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">  

    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>  
    <non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/jBossJaasPostgres</non-jta-data-source>  


    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>  
    <properties>  
       <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>  
    </properties>  
  </persistence-unit>  
</persistence>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  
<hibernate-configuration>  
  <session-factory>  
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" >org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/apvv</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.MeasurementDataColumn"/>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.Winding"/>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.Label"/>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.MeasurementColumn"/>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.Measurement"/>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.GroupApp"/>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.MeasurementDataColumnId"/>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.Location"/>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.UserApp"/>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.Company"/>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.LocationId"/>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.WindingTransformer"/>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.Manufacturer"/>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.Transformer"/>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.ColumnData"/>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.WindingTransformerId"/>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.City"/>  
    <mapping class="sk.fri.model.Measurand"/>  
  </session-factory>  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**jboss-web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jboss-web>  
  <security-domain>java:/jaas/apvvJaas</security-domain>  
  <context-root>/apvv</context-root>  
</jboss-web>
```

This is part of code where I produce **EntityManager**:

```
@Produces  
@RequestScoped  
public EntityManager produceEntityManager(){  
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("FRIApvvPU");        
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();  
    return em;  
}
```

Connection to Postgres database works fine I have tested it from wildfly console, because the datasource jBossJaasPostgres was successfully created.

I found answers to this questions but no answer worked for me.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I deleted the hibernate.cfg.xml and moved the configuration from this file to persistence.xml. Then I also removed all hibernate files from WEB-INF/lib folder, because WildFly has its own ones and this situation also possibly made a conflict. More details on this problem in this link : 
[JBoss Community Forum](https://community.jboss.org/thread/238096)

Comment: Add some relevant info from the link to your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I was developing a project with Hibernate and when I changed the server tomcat to Jboss(WildFly) I had some problems in my project because of Maven configuration(Pom.xml). The WildFly alredy had the jars that my project needed and it made a conflict.

I changed the compile to provided, so it was solved:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.21.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.21.Final</version>  
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: For me none from these approachs worked. Something else?

Answer (score 0):

It's connecting issues with data base. Just open your local database before deploying your code. Then it will work properly.